# Fixing Firebase Comments Section

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I implemented this Pen ( https:// codepen.io/joshbivens/pen/jbNJJR) in my Firebase account (Firebase Hosting -> upload HTML, CSS and JS via node.js command line), but it doesn't work. I made it exactly like the example, of course I have updated the database URL.

How can I fix that?

---

EDIT:

I try to make it more clear...

My question is: Why is this pen working, and my exact copy of it (with changed server url) isn't working?

I also tried to embed the newest version of firebase.js but also with the old (as in the pen) it doesn't work.

This is the code I use:

```js
const ref = new Firebase("https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com");
const form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", postComment);

const timeStamp = () => {
  let options = {
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    year: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute:'2-digit'
  };
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', options);
  return now;
};

function postComment(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

  if (name && comment) {
    ref.push({
      name: name,
      comment: comment,
      time: timeStamp()
    });
  }

  document.getElementById("name").value = '';
  document.getElementById("comment").value = '';
};

ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  let comment = snapshot.val();
  addComment(comment.name, comment.comment, comment.time);
});

const addComment = (name, comment, timeStamp) => {
  let comments = document.getElementById("comments");
  comments.innerHTML = `<hr><h4>${name} sagt<span>${timeStamp}</span></h4><p>${comment}</p>${comments.innerHTML}`;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700')

body
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif
  height: 100%
  margin-bottom: 50px
  background: cadetblue
  height: 100vh
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center

  

  

h4
  margin: 5px 20px
  
span
  float: right
  margin-right: 10px
  font-size: 12px
  font-weight: 300
  
hr
  border: 0
  height: 0
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)

.container
  display: flex
  justify-content: center

.comment-box
  width: 85%
  margin-top: 50px
  background: #fff
  padding: 5px
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  flex-direction: column

p
    margin: 0 30px 15px
    font-weight: 300
    color: #333
    word-wrap: break-word
    background: #EEE
    padding: 5px 10px

.header
  margin: 15px 20px
  font-size: 27px
  font-weight: 600

form
  margin: 10px 10px 30px 10px
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder
    color: #CCC
    font-weight: 300
  
input[type="text"], textarea
  margin: 5px 10px
  outline: none
  background: #efefef
  border: 0
  padding: 10px
      
textarea
  resize: none
  width: 85%
  
input[type="text"]
  width: 50%
  margin-bottom: 15px

button
  font-weight: 400
  margin: 12px 0 0 10px
  border: 0
  color: #fff
  font-size: 15px
  background: #D3775D
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px
  text-decoration: none
  transition: all .2s ease
  &:hover
    background: #C15322
  
.footer p
  float: right
  font-size: 13px
  margin-bottom: 10px
  background: #FFF
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="comment-box">
      <div class="comment-form">
        <div class="header">Add Your Comment</div>
        <form>
          <div> 
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <textarea id="comment" rows="3" cols="30" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">COMMENT</button>
        </form>  
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4 class="header">Comments</h4>
        <div id="comments"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"><hr><p>Test</p></div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Codepen, which is a great start. But please make sure the minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem is also in the question itself.

Comment: Ok, what I don't understand: I run the code snippet here, and it worked! (Of course the data isn't stored in the database, because I cannot publish the server url...)

I think my problem is the reference in HTML to JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not sure *what* doesn't work about the code. Is it not writing to the database? Not reading from the database? Or is it reading, but not adding to the HTML? Or is it adding to the HTML, but not styling it correctly? With the code you shared, it's hard for us to know what you're struggling with, which is why I shared the link on [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before.

Comment: Also note that: `new Firebase("https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com");` points to a really old Firebase SDK (about 3 years). I highly recommend picking a more up-to-date source to learn from, such as the Firebase documentation for web developers: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: Thank you for your patience!!

I will look at the new version.

What doesn't work? If I type in a name and comment, and click "COMMENT", nothing happens. Also when I reload the website, there are no comments.

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console output? Are there any relevant errors when you submit the data (and call `ref.push(...)`)?

Comment: Also note that the codepen you shared has a link to the version that uses the new API.

Comment: I hope that's what you mean. Firefox Development Tools - Console says: `TypeError: form is null` in `test.js` line 4
I also see `GET https://a-abcd-abc-123.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=1&ns=abcd-efg` twice with HTTP 200

Comment: The new codepen doesn't work, so I deleted the alert and made the old content visible and then it worked

Comment: Aha after I've activated "Block Temporary Disable" in Firefox, the new version works now

Comment: So I will test the new version, but thank you

Comment: One last questiion, if I want to use the Pen (new version), do I have to prepare my Firebase account for this purpose? I only updated the server urls.